# Android call two or more Web Service

Tags: android, web, service

Today, my App call one Web Service and Works fine, so, I want to add one more call web service when the first call finish how can I do that?, another question, in onTaskComplete method I validate if the Web Service get data or not

```
int status = ljsonObject.getInt("status")
```

If status variable value = -1 I have to show a message ..... How can I separete the correct message for the Web Service 1 and Web Service 2

Answer (score 1):

To orchestrate multiple Web service calls I recommend you use RxJava (Reactive Extensions for the JVM). When you start to learn it is quite difficult, but then you realize it is the most pro way to do that sort of things. Here you have a link to the library: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava :)